# Swift - Getting address from coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I have a local search that creates annotations for each search result. I'm trying to add an call out accessory to each of the annotations, and once that will be pressed, the Maps app will open and set directions on how to get to the certain location.

The problem that I am having is that in order for the call out accessory to work correctly, you have to get the address using place marks in the Address Book import. I've done plenty of searching and can't figure out how to set it up correctly where I can covert the annotation coordinates into a `kABPersonAddressStreetKey` so the Maps app can read it correctly. Below is my code for the search function, and the open Maps app function.

```
func performSearch() -> MKMapItem {

    matchingItems.removeAll()
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText.text
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.startWithCompletionHandler({(response:
        MKLocalSearchResponse!,
        error: NSError!) in

        if error != nil {
            println("Error occured in search: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response.mapItems.count == 0 {
            println("No matches found")
        } else {
            println("Matches found")

            for item in response.mapItems as! [MKMapItem] {
                println("Name = \(item.name)")
                println("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")

                self.matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
                println("Matching items = \(self.matchingItems.count)")

                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                var coordinates = annotation.coordinate
                var location = CLLocation(latitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: annotation.coordinate.longitude)
                var street = // Insert code here for getting address from coordinates
                var addressDictionary = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): street]
                var placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)
                var mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
                return mapItem

                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
                annotation.title = item.name
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

            }
        }
    })
}


func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!,
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
        let location = view.annotation as! FirstViewController
        let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
        location.performSearch().openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. You can generate a request for driving directions using lat/long coordinates just as easily as using addresses.

Here's what you do:

1. Get the MKMapItem for the user-selected pin
2. Create a second MKMapItem for the user's current location using the
   MKMapItem method mapItemForCurrentLocation().
3. Call the MKMapItem class method openMapsWithItems() passing in the
   two MKMapItems for the current location and the destination, and a
   launchOptions dictionary specifying MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving.

### Edit:

#### Here's how you'd create a map item for the user-tapped item:

In your calloutAccessoryControlTapped method you get passed an annotation view.
The MKAnnotationView class has an annotation property, an object that conforms to the MKAnnotation property.

An MKAnnotation object has a coordinate property.

You can fetch the annotation object from the annotation view, and the coordinate from the annotation object.

You would then take the coordinate and use it to create an MKPlacemark, using the `initWithCoordinate:addressDictionary:` method (passing in a nil addressDictionary).

That call might look like this:

```
let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(
      coordinate: fromCoordinate,
      addressDictionary: nil)
```

You'd then take the place mark and use it to create an MKMapItem, using the `initWithPlacemark:` method.

#### Getting an MKMapItem for the user's current location:

There is a single MKMapView method, `forCurrentLocation()` that returns a MKMapItem for the current location.

Comment: So all of the code for translating the coordinates to an address I don't need? You made it sound a lot simpler than I thought it would be.

Comment: That's correct. you can get directions using the current location and a lat/long for the destination.

Comment: On the part where you said "passing in the two MKMapItems for the current location and destination," can you specify on how to do that exactly? Also how to get the current selected MKMapItem, I'm not sure I'm doing that correctly.

Comment: I understand the process, but due to my lack of Swift knowledge I'm not sure how to "fetch the annotation object from the annotation view, and the coordinate from the annotation object." The rest I know how to do.

Comment: I spelled it out in pretty great detail. I'm not sure how to give you more info without writing your code for you. If you can't write basic statements in Swift you may be in over your head, and need to drop back and do more reading before you'r ready to take on something like this. I started with Swift by reading the Apple iBook "The Swift Programming Language."

Comment: I understand, and thank you for your help. I prefer to learn as I go, I'm basing my work off a few tutorials and what I've learned so far and Google searches, but I can't seem to figure this one out so I've come here.

Comment: So try and work through the steps I've outlined. Post back if you get stuck.

Comment: I think I've figured out the first two steps by creating an annotation variable: `var annotation = view.annotation`. Then creating a coordinate variable: `var coordinate = annotation.coordinate`. The part I'm stuck at is the `initWithCoordinate:addressDictionary:` method. I've searched the Class reference on the Apple Dev Library and referenced that, but I'm getting a bunch of weird errors. Here is what I'm trying: `var place mark = MKPlaceMark(init!(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, addressDictionary: nil))`

Comment: Your syntax for the init call is all wrong. I added sample code for creating a place mark to my answer.